# Side bar Menu toggle HTML with Angular 2+ material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-design

I have a page in my Angular application, where i need to have a side menu with toggle like below. When i click the icon, it must toggle.

On the top i have a reach textbox

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add two more things to your question: 1.) Add the code example of how much you have now, or at least the idea you got/you got stuck with. 2). Ask an actual question, like "how can I add ..."

Comment: Please also state: Which framework do you use ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-bsbtvg?file=app/app.component.html) is something similar I did a while back, just added a search on top. Maybe you can build on that and tell us what you need / where you struggle.

Comment: @FabianKüng perfect, this is what exactly i'm looking